# IntelliJ: Debugger not working in a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I am new to using IntelliJ and this seems to be a common problem having gone through similar questions but am still unable to use debugger in a Maven project.

After configuring the Debugger when I click on Debug I see following in my console:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151" -agentLib:jdwp=trasnport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:52485 server=n suspend=y 
...//Few project specific environment variables
Connected to target VM 127.0.0.1:52485
```

Note that the application is up and listening on port 8080 as I can access it from the browser and its a standalone Dropwizard application.

There is a cross on the break point and the debugger doesn't stop over it. Have tried removing Cache, restarting, deleting .idea folder, building Maven project but still the break point doesn't work.

Should the jdwp port also be 8080 and not 50000 something as shown above. I am unable to debug this in Eclipse as well. Can some one help me out what could be the solution. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What Run configuration do you use to start debugging process?

Comment: In the Run Configuration of Eclipse I have given Program arguements: "server <path of yaml file>" and then in the VM arguments also a couple of yaml file locations. Havent given anything more than this.